How to return MAX Date when multiple dates are showing in results of query?
I have a query that returns a payor, a recipient, and an updated date of when the payor ID changes for a recipient.
Currently, it's returning every record of an updated date, when I only want it to return the one MAX date (aka most recent)
SampleTable:



LeadPayorID
LeadRecipientID
UpdatedDate




99
640
9-26-2024


99
644
9-26-2024


99
663
9-30-2024


150
640
10-20-2023


150
644
10-15-2023


99
608
8-17-2024


150
230
4-13-2023


150
230
3-20-2024



Here is the code currently:
SELECT LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorId, MAX(UpdatedDate) AS UpdatedDate
    FROM LeadBilling
    WHERE LeadRecipientId != LeadPayorId
    GROUP BY LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorId

I was expecting it to give me one record per recipient, but it returns multiple records of the same recipient with different payors, when I only want one record returned based on the most recent updated date.
Here is what it's giving me:



LeadPayorID
LeadRecipientID
UpdatedDate




99
640
9-26-2024


99
644
9-26-2024


150
640
10-20-2023


150
644
10-15-2023


99
663
9-30-2024


150
230
3-20-2024



Here's what I want it to show:



LeadPayorID
LeadRecipientID
UpdatedDate




99
640
9-26-2024


99
644
9-26-2024


99
663
9-30-2024


150
230
3-20-2024



To clarify, I want JUST the row with the most recent updated date for a leadrecipientID, regardless of the leadpayorID. If lead payor ID 150 and 99 share a recipientID, I want the row that has the most recent UpdatedDate.
Thank you

Search for top 1 of group. See examples where they use Row_Number()

Can you also show us the expected result, i.e. provide a complete [mcve]. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Note that tables have rows, not records.

You still haven't tagged your rdbms as requested in the staging ground

And is the data you show your desired results or your actual results? You should show both and clearly label them

I don't understand why some IDs are not in the (expected or actual?) result. Why is there no row for LeadPayorID = 77 and LeadRecipientID = 512 for instance?

And why do you expect "one record per recipient", when your query clearly says you want one row per recipient and payor (GROUP BY LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorId)? This doesn't seem to make sense. Which of the two do you really want?

@daleK what I showed is what it's returning. What I'd like to have is ONLY the most recent updated date for a RecipientID. So the 99 -640 pair would show and not the 150-640 pair.

@thorstenKettner Sorry I didn't show the LeadPayorID 77 result. The 512 RecipientID returns just 1 row with the most recent updated date. However because LeadPayorIDs 99 and 150 have shared RecipientIDs, they are appearing multiple times. I just want the most recent updated date for a RecipientID, so it should return the LeadPayor 99 row for RecipientIDs 640 and 644, and leave out the 150 rows.

So show, as actual data, the results you wish to obtain. And also note SSMS is only a client UI - its not a database engine. I assume you want SQL Server?

I edited the question to show what I want to obtain, and tagged SQL Server. Sorry still new to this.

Most RDBMSs support window functions, which you can use to identify the record you wish to keep:
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorId, UpdatedDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorID ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC) as rn
       FROM LeadBilling
       WHERE LeadRecipientId != LeadPayorId
     ) as dt
WHERE rn = 1

That window function in the subquery generates a row number within each distinct LeadPayorID group ordered by the UpdatedDate. In the main query we keep the record with the rn of 1.
If you are on Snowflake, Teradata, Databricks, or any other RDBMS that supports the QUALIFY clause you can write this without the subquery like so:
SELECT LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorId, UpdatedDate
FROM LeadBilling
WHERE LeadRecipientId != LeadPayorId
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LeadRecipientId, LeadPayorID ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC) = 1


Thank you! I tried the top example (I'm in SSMS) and I'm getting an error on the final "WHERE rn = 1", it says incorrect syntax?

That's because I failed to include an alias for the subquery. I will fix the answer.

That's helpful thank you! The only issue I'm having with this is it's only returning one row per leadpayor entirely, like leadpayorid = 150 and leadrecipientid = 727. If a lead payor has multiple recipients, I need each of those rows to appear, but ONLY the most recent updated date.

Got it. You'll want to add LeadRecipientID into the PARTITION BY clause within the window function definition. This will cause the database to chunk up the windows/partitions by distinct LeadPayorID, LeadRecipientID combinations. I will update the answer.

Had to remove the LeadPayorID from the partition, but that worked! Thank you!

You need a nested query.  The inner query picks the max date, the outer query does the whole record.
SELECT a.LeadPayorId, a.LeadRecipientID, a.UpdatedDate 
FROM LeadBilling a,
(
    SELECT LeadRecipientId, MAX(UpdatedDate) AS UpdatedDate
    FROM LeadBilling
    GROUP BY LeadRecipientId
) b
WHERE a.LeadRecipientID = b.LeadRecipientID
  AND a.UpdatedDate = b.UpdatedDate
;

That could also be written as an INNER JOIN.
